# In Dart how to get the ID of clicked target object?

Tags: dom, mouseevent, dart

For the Dart code below:

```
for(var Element in Element_list){
  Element.onClick.listen((event){
  //some code
  });
}
```

How to determine the ID of the clicked object? I tried Element.atrributes["id"] and would only get the type of the Element like "label" or "button".

How to get the ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `event.target.id` or `event.target.attributes['id']`. Here is a little example (assume you have an element with id 'text'):

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  query("#text").onClick.listen((Event event) {
    print(event.target.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: However, it DOES NOT work for SVG element. How to make it work for SVG element?